# Decision Boundary will not overlay all scatter plot

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, scikit-learn, knn

I am developing a `Knn` model with `Decision Boundary` on normalised data. I wanted to separate each `species` of the `iris` dataset based on additional column values (reproducible example). The extra column is supposed to represent colours for the species.

Here is what I have tried, sample data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.neighbors import NeighborhoodComponentsAnalysis
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

n_neighbors = 3
random_state = 0

iris = datasets.load_iris()

p=np.tile(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 30)
np.random.shuffle(p)

ir = pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
ir[4] = p
ir[5] = iris.target
print(ir.iloc[:,0:5])
X = ir.iloc[:,0:5].groupby(by=4).apply(lambda x: np.delete(x.values, 4, axis=1))
y = ir.iloc[:,4:6].groupby(by=4).apply(lambda x: np.delete(x.values, 0, axis=1))

testData(X, y, size=[2,2])
```

Algorithm to plot:

```
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay
from typing import List

def testData(X,y, size: List[int]):
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(size[0], size[1], figsize=(8, 8))
    model = make_pipeline(
        StandardScaler(),
        NeighborhoodComponentsAnalysis(n_components=2, random_state=random_state),
    )
    # Use a nearest neighbor classifier to evaluate the methods
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
    
    # Make a list of the methods to be compared
    #dim_reduction_methods = [("NCA", nca)]
    
    # plt.figure()
    for axs, (k, v), (ks, vl) in zip(axarr.flat,X.items(), y.items()):
        dim = len(v[0])
        n_classes = len(np.unique(vl))
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(v, vl, test_size=0.5, stratify=vl, random_state=random_state)
        
        # Fit the method's model
        try:
            model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
            print('yes')
        except:
            print('no')
            continue
    
        # Fit a nearest neighbor classifier on the embedded training set
        knn.fit(model.transform(X_train), y_train.ravel())
    
        # Compute the nearest neighbor accuracy on the embedded test set
        acc_knn = knn.score(model.transform(X_test), y_test)
    
        # Embed the data set in 2 dimensions using the fitted model
        X_embedded = model.transform(v)
        xs = X_embedded[:, 0]
        ys = X_embedded[:, 1]
        scalex = 1.0/(xs.max() - xs.min())
        scaley = 1.0/(ys.max() - ys.min())
        # Plot the projected points and show the evaluation score
        DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
        knn, v, alpha=0.4,ax=axs, response_method="predict")
        
        axs.scatter(xs*scalex, ys*scaley, c=vl, s=30, cmap="Set1", edgecolor = 'black')
        #plt.title(
        #    "{}, KNN (k={})\nTest accuracy = {:.2f}".format('Knn', n_neighbors, acc_knn)
        #)
    plt.show()
```

This produces the following plots:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have added the following in replacement:

```
 disp = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
        knn, X_embedded, alpha=0.4,ax=axs, response_method="predict")
        
        disp.ax_.scatter(xs*scalex, ys*scaley, c=vl, s=30, cmap="Set1", edgecolor = 'black')
```

so I replaced `X_embedded` for `v` in the script. However, the voronoi diagram pathways are not correctly adjusted to the scale of the scatterplot values. I get instead:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the

`scalex` and `scaley` values in the scatterplot meant the points were re-scaled. Therefore, removing this I get the correct plot:
[image]